# What is the best way to connect grease pencil animations?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I created two grease objects (but same character) with different animations. One is walking. The other one is running. What is the best way to connect the two so that the character can be seen walking and then running in one smooth connection.

Comment: I don't really know the answer but I can guess that this is done in regular Blender objects by mixing animation in the Action Editor (now called the Non Linear Editor). But I don't think that Grease Pencil animations are defined in the NLE. I think you may have to blend drawing by hand

Comment: yep, pretty sure you're gonna have to draw the inbetweens yourself. Could be easier to only have the one object and use the offset modifier